# Is there a perfect solution that can display swf files with Qt 5.7 in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: qt, flash, ubuntu

My project need I achieve this function.

And I'd crawled lots of methods online , unfortunately , they all doesn't work.

I ever used the QAxWidget widget , that works ,but only in Windows OS.

Now I'm in Ubuntu 16.04. So How can I display a flash file in my Qt program ? My Qt version is 5.7 .

I have tried (But it also doesn't work) :

```
QWebEngineView view; 
QWebEngineSettings *websetting = view.settings(); 
websetting->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::PluginsEnabled, true); 
view.load( QUrl(QStringLiteral("/Users/yrd241/Desktop/ic_phiz‌​_action.swf") ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `QWebEngineView` with `QWebEngineSettings::PluginsEnabled` enabled? According to docs you can enable "Pepper Plugin API" which supports Flash player. This feature was introduced in [Qt 5.6](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qtwebengine-features.html#pepper-plugin-api)

Comment: Thanks for answer!   Do you mean , if I use QWebEngineView , I  need to configure an web server locally  and then put my flash file onto it ?   Are there some examples or tutorials that I can study?

Comment: No need to make local server - you can still load file from hdd

Comment: I write code like this :QWebEngineView view;
QWebEngineSettings *websetting = view.settings();
websetting->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
view.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("/Users/yrd241/Desktop/ic_phiz_action.swf")));

Comment: But it also doesn't work. Is there something wrong ?

Comment: Did you read the docs? You probably need to register plugin, also you need to have pepper flash player plugin on your machine.

Comment: yes,I'v read. As they said,"The Pepper Flash player plugin can be loaded automatically if it is installed in one of the following locations, depending on the platform", and my platform is Mac ox , so I copied the PepperFlashPlayer.plugin to the /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/PepperFlashPlayer/, but I got this error when I run my code: "Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x7face6c14c60 </Library/Internet Plug-Ins/PepperFlashPlayer/PepperFlashPlayer.plugin> (not loaded)".